# Using another heroku repository as submodule from the heroku server?

Tags: git, heroku, ssh-keys

I have two projects, where the one uses another as an submodule. After lots of trying and failing I ended up thinking to move the remote submodule to the same heroku account as an new project, thinking that I could do away with user authorization.

But the authorization still does not work:

```
remote: Git submodules detected, installing:
remote: Submodule 'foo' (ssh://git@heroku.com/foo.git) registered for path 'foo'
remote: Cloning into 'foo'...
remote: Host key verification failed.
remote: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote:
remote: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
remote: and the repository exists.
```

What kind of settings should I give to the Heroku? Setting heroku ssh keys did not seem to work, or I did something wrong: ssh -vvv heroku.com seems to return access granted.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this, because Heroku's Git repository hosting is private, and requires your SSH key to work.

The reason your submodule works LOCALLY is that your SSH key is able to pull down all your Heroku Git repos. The reason it doesn't work ON Heroku is that the Heroku environment is very restricted. It won't have your local SSH keys on it. This means there's no way to make that work.

There are a few things you can do:

- Make your submodule public on Github or some other host.
- Turn your submodule into a Heroku project of its own, and expose an API that you call from your existing Heroku project.
- Get rid of the submodule completely and just embed your source.

I realize that's sort of annoying, but the problem here is that you can't use a private submodule in an untrusted environment with no SSH credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue for the last week myself. The last option is sounding more and more like the way i might end up going. I hate to combine two separate repos but I can't find a way around it.